# Proper way to format text when not using a lot of math

Tags: formatting

I'm confused about text formatting, I see almost everywhere the `\text` command, which I believe is part of the `amsmath` package?

If I'm doing mostly writing with just a bit of math here and there, is using the `\text` command preferred or is there another method more native to latex without the `amsmath` package for formatting text?

Comment: Could you give an example? If you just mean "a document containing a lot of prose with only a few simple equations", then you don't have to worry about `\text`. (The `\text` macro is mostly for when you want to do things such as insert a little bit of prose into some mathematics.)

Comment: Your question isn't so clear what do you mean by "formatting text"  `\text` is for formatting text in math mode (you could use `\mbox` instead if you don't need it to get smaller in subscripts) but do you need text in math at all?

Comment: I am doing mostly prose, a couple of equations but very little. I was only aware of the \text command for changing text to italic, bold, small caps, etc. This command however I am starting to realize is part of the math package and I'm wondering if there is a better command for altering text this way that isn't specific for mathematical text.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To write a simple document without very much math, you don't have to do anything special; and you certainly don't need the `\text` macro.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

%% Uncomment the following line to use an AMSmath equation
%\usepackage{amsmath}

\title{A simple document consisting mostly of text}
\author{Niel de Beaudrap}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{A section title}

The following is a simple displayed un-numbered equation.
\[
  E = mc^2
\]
%% Uncomment the following as desired.
% In many cases, it's useful to use an equation environment
% from the AMSmath package. The following is a simple example
% which gives the displayed equation a number:
%\begin{equation}
%  \mathbf{F} := \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \mathbf{p}
%\end{equation}
You can write as much prose as you want outside of the math environments
you use (indeed, you don't have to use \emph{any} math environments if
you don't want to).

\end{document}
```

Give that a try. You might want to investigate [some simple introductory references for LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-is-the-best-book-to-start-learning-latex), if you're starting from scratch.